# Nagios3 check_httpname gives 503 response; from command line I get a 200 response

Tags: http, nagios

We're using Nagios to monitor our site (and a bunch of other stuff.) For some odd reason, when I test out the command

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H 'domainname.com'
```

the response that comes back is `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` but when I set up the service to do it:

```
# Check that domain is running
define service {
    hostgroup_name                  hostgroup
    service_description             host site
    check_command                   check_httpname!domainname.com
    use                             generic-service
    notification_interval           1; set > 0 if you want to be renotified
}
```

the response that comes back is `HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable`.

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: Can you post the command definition of `check_httpname`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why I can't add a comment but can you might want to verify your address and host_name in the host definition.  I've been stuck in situations where the command line check script works but the GUI is telling me something else.  Usually it's a typo in the address field.

Comment: Might be a typo in the check_httpname command definition in command.cfg too, per ErikA's question above.

Comment: It was in fact the host_name and address. I was trying to get localhost to use a different hostname. Just went through and added a new host and therefore a new host_name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Heres how to fix this!

You have to edit the /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg and change the https arument **"-I" to "-H"**

This will tell it to lookup hostname instead of an dip-address specified in your http_check block in server config:
/usr/local/nagios/etc/servers/yourserver.cfg

**from:**

```
    # 'check_http' command definition
define command{
        command_name    check_http
        command_line    $USER1$/check_http -I $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$
        }
```

**To:**

```
    # 'check_http' command definition
define command{
        command_name    check_http
        command_line    $USER1$/check_http -H $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$
        }
```